# 1120: Access of undefined property StageDisplayState

Tags: actionscript-3

When I use the fullscreen code to make my flash game show up in fullscreen.

```
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

Somehow, it doesn't work and show up this error saying StageDisplayState is not defined.

My code is in the enterframe of the main document class.

Comment: Are you sure you imported it? `import flash.display.StageDisplayState;`

Comment: why would you do that in a enterframe? That means you change the displayState every frame, while you better do it only once, or better, letter the user trigger it by clicking a button.

Comment: @Marijn You're actually right, sorry about that.

Comment: @Marijn It's not only better, It should be, like [Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS2E9C7F3B-6A7C-4c5d-8ADD-5B23446FBEEB.html) said about that (in Flash Player) : *In Flash Player, full-screen mode can only be initiated through ActionScript in response to a mouse click (including right-click) or keypress ...*.

Comment: @akmozo that's only for Flash Web, though. You can set your Air App to fullscreen whenever you want.

Comment: @DodgerThud Yes, of course, that's why I said "in Flash Player".

Comment: @Soldiers You can also simply do : `stage.displayState = "fullScreen";` without importing nothing.